# Retrieve data from JSON web service with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a web service which works fine, when I open it manually and type the parameters in manually. For example:

When I navigate to url.url/webservice.php?region=NY it gives me all the data I need from my database. Now I want to type in a city in an input field and let ajax do the rest.

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="NY" name="myText" id="input">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="mySubmit" id="submit" onClick="changeView()">
</form>
```

So now, when I type something in the input field Ajax should send an request to my webservice and get the data.

My web service looks like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json"); 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','ttzaferis');
$array = array();
$region = $_GET['region'];
if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT lon, lat FROM pointsofinterest WHERE region = '".$region."'")){
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($array, $tempArray); 
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

I have now only problems on the Ajax-part. I can't understand how to make it work. I tried the following

```
function changeView(){
    var region = document.getElementById('input').value;
    alert(region);
    $j.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
        url: 'webservice.php',
        data: region,
        success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {  
        alert("test");
    }
});
}
```

I don't understand what the problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: You're submiting the form and the ajax never happens. change submit to button and it'll work.

Comment: Is the client page and REST server in same domain?

Comment: @eric.itzhak - I did this <input type="button" onClick="changeView()" name="mySubmit"> and it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Broncha - Everything is on the same server(local) and in the same dierctory. So there shouldn't be any problem with paths

Comment: Does your console show anything? what's being sent in the network tab?

Comment: And you're sending post data but setting data, i'm not sure but might be a problem... did you try adding it to the url as regular get data?

Comment: @eric.itzhak - no errors in the console. But the network tab seems to solve the problem a bit, If i'm right. It sends GET webservice.php?NY. The region= is missing, right?

Comment: I don't see that you're canceling the normal form submit.

Comment: That makes sense -- try `data: $('#input').closest('form').serialize()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually send get data like this :

```
  $j.ajax({
    url: 'webservice.php?region='+region,

    success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {  
    alert("test");
}
});
```

Which according to your comments should solve this. I don't know if it's possible sending via data, but if it is then you should do something like this :

```
  $j.ajax({
    url: 'webservice.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {region : region},
    success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {  
    alert(response.somekey);
}
});
```

Or seirlizing it, But yet again, i'm not sure if it'll work. Note that i added `dataType`, though jQuery usually tries to find out what the dataType will be, won't hurt to add it

Comment: I did the second one! That works. May I ask how I now get the data from the JSON-Request in my alert window?

It should be something like 
    var example = data[0].example;
    alert(example);

right?

Comment: @TheoTzaferis Revised answer. if you don't use keys you can use indexes ya.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this but this is totally beyond my skill level and I have absolutely no idea what to do now. What I've done is googling a bit, and I found this part here:

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    alert(key);
});;

But, this doesn't alert me anything. I thought I can somehow get the data with data.fieldname, but when I type in data. dreamweaver just suggests me protype or region, what is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @TheoTzaferis `each` is in cases you wanna loop through the data, and ofcourse looping through `data` won't give you anything, since you called the result `response` so you should `$.each(response, function(key,val)`

Comment: Seems about right, now when I click the ok button I get
$.each(response, function(key, val) {
    alert(key+ " and " +val); 
    });;

0 and [object Object]

I'm sorry, I would like to upvote you, but my reputation is not high enough yet. You are a really big help

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pUU7N/)

I also included the webservice.php in this link

Comment: I guess I solved it. I just used key.lat and key.lon (these are my fields in json)